# How to get access to a locked MS Access database

Tags: ms-access

I have a multi-user split access DB with a front end and back end on a network drive. I often need to make structural changes to the back end of the database but the file is always locked due to the frequent use of the file by many users and the fact that nobody seems to be able to close the file when they are finished with it.

When I need to modify the file I have to contact IT to kick everyone out of the file from the server which is a real pain.

I've tried things like coding an auto close timeout on the FE and a few other vba methods but over time there will always be something that causes the FE to hang or something before running the necessary code leaving the BE locked.

Is there any way to get access to the file without needing access to the Server settings?

Comment: Use [Microsoft Jet Database Engine Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Unless you implement a listener on the FE that looks at a flag on the BE and closes the FE when the BE flag is set (it sounds as if you've tried something like that), there is no way to do what you want.  You can't even open the BE exclusively unless there are no other users.  This is just one of the reasons that Access is not really a preferred multi-user DB solution.

Comment: I thought as much but I wanted to be sure. The plan is to move to a MySQL based setup soon so I'll just put up with the hassle for another while! Thanks